# Diffusers bug: "UNet2DConditionModel" has no attribute "weight"

Tags: python, stable-diffusion, diffusers, safe-tensors

When using the official script "convert_lora_safetensor_to_diffusers.py", I tried to load a  basemodel by using `pipeline = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(base_model_path, torch_dtype=torch.float32)` and combine it with lora weights.

`curr_layer = pipeline.unet`

`curr_layer.weight.data += alpha * torch.mm(weight_up, weight_down)`

And this error appeared:

`Modulist Object has no attribute weight`

I use `dir`  and the result is:
[image]

I wonder what's wrong with my diffusers or how I can fix this.